# How to calculate balance in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Query which Result is

```
Code      id    Date        Amount  Paid      Balance
------------------------------------------------------
INV-000001  0   10/25/2019  50000   420       0
INV-000001  0   10/25/2019  50000   90        0
INV-000001  0   10/25/2019  50000   100       0
INV-000002  0   10/30/2019  25000   0         0
INV-000003  0   10/30/2019  25000   0         0
INV-000004  0   10/30/2019  25000   0         0
```

I want to calculate the balance in SQL. e.g.,

in 1st row, the amount is 50000 and paid 420 so balance is 49580. In second-row balance will be 50000 - 90 -(first-row balance 420) = 49490

```
SELECT p.Code
    ,p.DATE
    ,p.STATUS
    ,'' AS Customer
    ,InvoiceAmount
    ,ISNULL(Paid, 0) AS Paid
    ,0 AS balance
FROM purchaseinvmaster p
LEFT OUTER JOIN InvoiceVoucherMap i ON i.InvoiceId = p.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN debitcreditmaster d ON i.VoucherId = d.id
```

Comment: i can breif if anyone cannot understand my question

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: This is a query? Can you share the SQL statement which generates the data, please?

Comment: Is there another column to order the transactions within a single date? Or is the `Date` column actually a `DATETIME`?

Comment: @EricBrandt On point. My answer may be inaccurate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  p.Code, 
         InvoiceAmount , ISNULL(Paid,0) as Paid,
        InvoiceAmount - SUM(ISNULL(Paid,0)) OVER (ORDER BY p.id ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS Balance
from purchaseinvmaster p
```

Comment: While this code solves the OP answer you should always describe your code how it works as any post is read by the future readers which makes your post more valuable for the long term.

Comment: `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` is not really needed, since it's the default window frame. Anyway +1 for the `ISNULL()`.

Comment: Instead of recalculating the balance for all the existing rows, what if the problem was to insert a new row and calculate the resulting balance for this new row based on the most recent one? and based on all previous rows ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention which database you are using, but you can use a standard window function to compute the balance. For example:

```
select
  *,
  amount - sum(paid) over(order by date) as balance
from t
```

Comment: sql server i guess

Answer (score 0):

Based on the `ISNULL()` in the base query, I'm assuming you're working on SQL Server, but this should work with minor tweaks on most major platforms.

I'm further assuming that the `DATE` column is just a date, not a datetime. That means we need to impose an order on the transactions that occur on the same date. To do that, I took your base query and wrapped it in a Common Table Expression (CTE) and added a simple `ROW-NUMBER()` to the results. One of your tables might have a column that suggests a better order, but without one, this will do. It uses the clause `ORDER BY (SELECT 0)` because the window function requires an order by, but we don't have an ordering column to reference.

After that, in the main query, use a windowed `SUM` to get your running total of payments.

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT 
     p.Code
    ,p.DATE
    ,p.STATUS
    ,'' AS Customer
    ,InvoiceAmount
    ,ISNULL(Paid, 0) AS Paid
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.Code ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS OrdinalNbr
  FROM purchaseinvmaster p
  LEFT OUTER JOIN InvoiceVoucherMap i
    ON i.InvoiceId = p.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN debitcreditmaster d
    ON i.VoucherId = d.id
)
  SELECT 
     Code
    ,DATE
    ,STATUS
    ,Customer
    ,InvoiceAmount
    ,Paid
    ,Balance = InvoiceAmount - (SUM(Paid) OVER (PARTITION BY Code ORDER BY OrdinalNbr))
  FROM 
    cte;
```